# How to test api called when submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I have LoginForm template using Antd Form passed onFinish function to prop onFinish.

Here is my onFinish function:
inside this function called api from class method Services and AuthService

```
const onFinish = async (values) => {
 setLoad(true);

 service.authService
  .login(values.username, values.password)
  .then((respon) => 
.
.
.
```

My test:

```
jest.mock("../service");

test.only("if login success", checkCanSubmitLogin);

const checkCanSubmitLogin = async () => {
      const expectedText = `Welcome ${correctUsername}`;
      login(correctUsername, correctPassword);
    
      await waitForElement(async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        expect(await screen.findByText(expectedText)).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
      login.mockRestore();
    };
const login = (username, password) => {
  const onFinishMock = jest.fn();

  renderLoginForm(onFinishMock);

  act(() => {
    fireEvent.change(getInputByPlaceHolder(/Username/), {
      target: { value: username },
    });
    fireEvent.change(getInputByPlaceHolder(/Password/), {
      target: { value: password },
    });
  });

  const loginSubmitButton = screen.getByRole("button", {
    name: /login/i,
  });
  fireEvent.submit(loginSubmitButton);

  expect(service.authServices).toHaveBeenCalledWith(username, password);
};

const renderLoginForm = (onFinishMock) => {
  act(() => {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginForm onFinishMock={onFinishMock} />
      </Provider>
    );
  });
};


 const getInputByPlaceHolder = (placeHolder) => {
  return screen.getByPlaceholderText(placeHolder);
};
```

I got failed test and error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login')

  43 |
  44 |     service.authService
> 45 |       .login(values.username, values.password)
     |        ^
```

I'm stuck with this test many days. I confused with mock test and try to test class with this doc https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks but still stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by mock

```
  function mockServices() {
  jest.mock("../service", () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((axiosInstance) => {
      return {
        axiosInstance,
        authService: {
          login: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve()),
        },
      };
    });
  });
  let service = new Services(Axios.defaults);
  return service;
}
```